# Uploading a file to a website when working with selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am writing a script for automatic testing of the site and I cannot upload a test file to the site. There is no field for entering a link to a file, only the "Select file" button and a windows dialog box opens. Is it possible to specify a link to a file in this window and upload it automatically, or can you tell me what other options there may be? The html code of the button itself looks like this:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" ng-disabled="src.uploadingStart" plupload="src.fileUpload.url" plupload-options="src.fileUpload.options" plupload-callbacks="src.fileUpload.callbacks" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">Select file</button>
    <span ng-show="dndSupport" class="ng-binding">or move the file to the forms</span>
    <div id="html5_1g120b0blv5k9rn1kma15kg1okc2j_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1g120b0blv5k9rn1kma15kg1okc2j" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" accept=".zip,.7z" tabindex="-1"></div>
        <input id="html5_1g120b0blv5k9rn1kma15kg1okc2j" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" accept=".zip,.7z" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: I have seen this answer, but in this case I will be tied to the windows system, and it is planned that this code will be executed on jenkins, so I am looking for a solution

Comment: pyautogui is a crossplatform solution so it shouldn't be a problem.